# how to check if the input value matches any value within an array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, g++

how am i going to do this with if..else, do..while?

this program should prompt the user to input college name and output the ranking of the college, and if the user input an incorrect name, the program should output a message that an incorrect name has been entered.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string college[] = {"Baylor", "Colorado", "Iowa State",
                        "Kansas", "Kansas State", "Missouri",
                        "Nebraska", "Oklahoma", "Oklahoma State",
                        "Texas", "Texas A&M", "Texas Tech"};
    int conferenceRanking[] = {12, 11, 10, 9, 5, 8,
                                3, 2, 7, 1, 6, 4};

    for (if)
    {
        cout << "Enter the name of a Big Twelve College: " << college[count]
         << college << "\n's ranking is " << conferenceRanking[count]
         << "\n" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[sample] This is the output what i want to come up with

```
Enter the name of a Big Twelve College: Nebraska
Nebraska's ranking is 3
```

Comment: What exactly is this `for (if)` ?

Comment: [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)?

Comment: because i am not sure what am i going to use whether for if..else or do while, i typed `for (if)`  @DimChtz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go a little more complex way and use a map for holding the data and for getting the college from the command line std::getline, because it detects spaces and puts them in the string. After reading the name it iterates over the already created map to find the college we are looking for. It then checks the iterator if it was found or not! You should check some C++ Tutorials or a good book to learn the basics of C++.

(this approach is using C++11 standard, so be sure your compiler is compatible)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{
        std::map<std::string, int> colleges = {
            {"Baylor", 12},
            {"Colorado", 11},
            {"Iowa State", 10},
            {"Kansas", 9},
            {"Kansas State", 5},
            {"Missouri", 8},
            {"Nebraska", 3},
            {"Oklahoma", 2},
            {"Oklahoma State", 7},
            {"Texas", 1},
            {"Texas A&M", 6},
            {"Texas Tech", 4}
        };

        std::cout << "to end enter: exit";

        bool p = true;
        while(p){
            std::string name;

            std::cout << "Enter the name of a Big Twelve College: ";
            std::getline(std::cin, name);

            if(name == "exit"){
                    p = false;
                    break;
            }

            std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it = colleges.find(name);
            if (it != colleges.end()){
                    std::cout << it->first << "'s ranking is " << it->second << "!" << std::endl;
            }else{
                    std::cout << "No college found!, try again!" << std::endl;
            }
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map to save your ranks, which will later help you access your ranks by name really easily. 
You can also keep a boolean variable indicating whether the current user input exists in you list, and use it to decide whether the user should get his/her answer, or be prompted again for some college name.

Here is an example main function that demonstrates:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 std::unordered_map<std::string, int> collegeRanks = {
    {"Baylor",12},
    {"Colorado",11},
    {"Iowa State",10}
};
//etc...

bool finished = false; 
string userInput;

while(!finished){

    cout << endl << "Enter the name of a Big Twelve College: ";
    getline (std::cin,userInput);
    std::unordered_map<std::string,int>::const_iterator nameAndRank = collegeRanks.find (userInput);
    if ( nameAndRank == collegeRanks.end() ){
        // Not found :(
        finished = false;
        cout << endl << userInput << " does not exist in our database... try another college name!" << endl;
        userInput = "";
    }
    else{
        // Found :) 
        finished = true;
        cout << userInput << "'s rank is " << std::to_string(nameAndRank->second) << endl;
    }

}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply with the arrays you have without using a map (if you want to). Consider the code below.

```
bool has = false; 
cout << "Enter college name\n";
string name;
cin >> name;
for(int i=0; i<12; i++){
    if(college[i].compare(name) == 0){
        has = true;
        cout << "Ranking of " << college[i] << " is " << conferenceRanking[i];
    }
}
//check if the name entered by user exists
if(has == false)
cout << "The college name entered does not exist";
```

The `bool` variable `has` determines whether the college name entered by user exists in the array `college[]` or not. If a match is found, value of `has` is changed to `true`.